# i have a django code where if we enter url/music it displays a line and url/music /65 (any integer) then it shows another page

Tags: django

the page with the integer provided is showing not found 404

```
from django.urls import path  
from . import views  



urlpatterns = [  
    path('',views.index,name='index'),  
    path('(?p<album_id>[0-9]+)',views.detail,name='detail'),     
]
```

inside views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse  
def index(request):  
    return HttpResponse("this is the music app homepage")  
def detail(requests,album_id):  
    return HttpResponse("details for "+ str(album_id))
```

expected - details for 65(entered integer)
actual-404 not found

Comment: Set your debug to True in your settings file and try again. That should give a detailed stack trace and error message instead of a 404

Comment: @dfundako how do i do that? i just started django

Comment: You should go do the tutorial on the django docs site.

Comment: @dfundako they just wrote give brackets identify the type of data etc the problem is i cant find what is did wrong in my code that it shows 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use `path('<int:album_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),`?

Comment: You're welcome. I'll appreciate you to select my answer.